# How would I import a variable's stored value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

If I use this code:

```
parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory', type=str, metavar='', required=True,
                help='Directory that files in question are located.')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--filename', type=str, metavar='', required=False,
                help='filename without .py extension.')

module_path = args.directory
file_name = args.filename
sys.path.append(module_path)
```

And now I want to print some variable within that file doing something like this:

```
import file_name
print(file_name.flight_date)
```

With this I get the error that file_name is not a module. Now if I go in and manually enter the value that file_name has stored then I have no problems. I do not want to manually put this in the script though because the value of file_name will change with different command line arguments.

I want the variable value to be what I am importing and not the variable itself but I do not know how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import importlib

i = importlib.import_module(file_name)
```

In your case then it'd be `print(i.flight_date)` after that